# Error: Make sure ant is installed and add to your path error

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant

I am trying to work on turning JQuery Mobile to android using PhoneGap
I have followed the tutorial, Installed Ant, Java JDK, Android SDK and Phone gap
When I execute this commnad `C:\Android\cordova\cordova-3.0.0\bin>create C:\Android\Project\PhoneGap_example com.test.example projectname` 
I get the following error::

> ERROR: executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add to your path.

I have also create the environment variables when I type in echo %ANT_HOME% in my Command prompt (Windows7) I get the path which is correct. But When I type in ant -version, it displays

> 'ant' is not recoganizd as an internal or external command
>   How can I fix this error

Comment: Is it on your `%PATH%`?

Comment: Yes I have added %ANT_HOME%\bin in my path

Comment: Could you post your PATH? Also try going to the %ANT_HOME%/bin directory and running ant -version.

Comment: >%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools; %ANDROID_HOME%\platforms; and my original path to %ANT_HOME%is C:\android\ANT

Comment: I get following error on running ant -version in bin file of ant  "Error: Count not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcer"

Comment: Do you have ant-launcher.jar in %ANT_HOME%/lib?  Also are you also declaring %ANT_HOME% before you declare the PATH?

Comment: Yeah I declared new variable first and then ant_home in my path and Yes I do have ant-launcher.jar as a zipped file in my lib